# Why can't Dart infer types in redirecting constructor?

Tags: dart

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```dart
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}

class Foo<T extends Parent> {
  final T t;
  Foo(this.t);

  Foo.one(Child child) : this(child); // Compile error
}
```

> The argument type 'Child' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'T'.

Why can't I pass `Child` in redirecting constructor, in other words, why doesn't Dart know that `Child` satisfies `T extends Parent` relationship? Though I can do

```dart
void main() => Foo(Child());
```

---

**Note:** I'm looking for a reason as to *why* I can't do that. Please don't post answers to use `this(child as T)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the code is not valid since you could do:

```dart
class Monster extends Parent {}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo<Monster>.one(Child());
}
```

Which is a problem since `Monster` does extend from `Parent` but the constructor argument takes a `Child` and will then try assign this to `T` which is `Monster`.

If we do the change you don't want:

```dart
Foo.one(Child child) : this(child as T);
```

Then we will get the error:

```
type 'Child' is not a subtype of type 'Monster' in type cast
#0      new Foo.one (./bin/example1.dart:8:37)
#1      main (./bin/example1.dart:14:15)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#3      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)
```

So you cannot say that `Child` can always be assigned to a variable `T` where `T extends Parent`.